# Excel conditional array duplicating result

Tags: excel, array-formulas

I'm trying to understand why

```
{=COUNT(IF({TRUE, FALSE, TRUE}, {3,4,5}))}
```

**returns 2** (which is the *expected* result) but the following **returns 6**

```
{=COUNT(IF({TRUE,FALSE,TRUE}, A1:A3))}
```

Here is a snapshot of the result
[image]

The formula evaluation shows what is happening
[image]

***NOTE***: This is a simplified version of a problem I am facing(i.e: it **isn't just a curiosity** question)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two formulas are not equivalent, your second formula is equivalent to this:

`=COUNT(IF({TRUE, FALSE, TRUE}, {3;4;5}))`

Note: `{3;4;5}` not `{3,4,5}`

That will also return 6. As you can see from the evaluation it returns a `3x3` matrix with 6 numbers hence that result

If you want the result to be 2 you need to transpose `A1:A3` like this

`=COUNT(IF({TRUE,FALSE,TRUE}, TRANSPOSE(A1:A3)))`

.....or use a **row** of values like `B2:D2` in place of `A1:A3`

Comment: Thank you, yes i found it a bit odd previously it was returning 2 when it was row based. If i may ask, why is not working if it is column based. I don't want to transpose it as i have 10,000 rows and i fear there might be a performance hit as this formula will be applied to every row.

Comment: I wouldn't say it's not working - it's doing what I would expect - if you compare a row to a column in excel you will get a matrix result, e.g. = `=A1:A5=B1:F1` gives you a 5x5 matrix result

Comment: @fuadj Probably stating the obvious, but it is also possible to get your desired result by transposing the array of `TRUE`/`FALSE` values.